# Rasbperry 4g usb modem + WIFI priority

Tags: networking, wifi, modem

When i connect raspberry to router by WIFI and plug usb modem - wifi have priority over internet.

i need that 3g modem will get internet and have priority over WIFI.
but i still can connect by local network to raspberry.
Hope someone will help. thank you

Comment: You wrote you want to connect to the RasPi by local network. Do you have an access point running on the RasPi you want to connect to? If you do not want this connection then just switch of wifi.

Comment: @Ingo i connect raspberry to router by WIFI.

Comment: Please establish a connection with the modem, then do `ip addr` and `ip route`, edit your question and insert the output of the commands.